# Magento Import: Media Gallery Image Position

Tags: import, magento-community, magmi

I just wondered if this has come across before but I am importing products into Magento via CSV and would like to set the order of the images in which they appear.

Ideally to do this via the import.

I did some digging and do see a field in the code, '_media_position'

: ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php

```
'_media_position'       => $mediaRow['position'],
```

I would happen to guess I use this in a CSV header item and can import the position of each image. As I opted to use Magmi to handle the import I would add this like

_media_position

1;2;3

This does not seem to work and open to suggests for this.

I am using Magento 1.8 but this does not seem to work on Magento 1.7 or 1.9. All other fields import successfully.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**_media_position** column  with start **0**

[image]